# Removing image accessibility

Tags: javascript, python, html, image, flask

I have a web page that is feed from flask a link to a picture. I have it so the image disappears after a second or two. However, if you look at the page source you can still get the picture, via finding the exact url for the picture. How do I remove access to the url or remove the picture from the url so that the user can no longer view the image after it disappears.

Html Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var c = document.getElementById('image');
        console.log(typeof(c));
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#des').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }, 1750);
        fs.unlink("{{ url_for('static', filename = '1l1l1lI1lIlIlIlI1IlI1II1l1.jpg') }}");
        removeElement(c)
        storage.clear(c);
        sessionStorage.clear(c);
    });
</script>

<div id="des">
    <img id="image" src="{{ url_for('static', filename = '1l1l1lI1lIlIlIlI1IlI1II1l1.jpg') }}"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import make_response
from functools import wraps, update_wrapper
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, \
    render_template, flash

app = Flask(__name__)  # create the application instance
app.config.from_object(__name__)  # load config from this file , flaskr.py

def nocache(view):
    @wraps(view)
    def no_cache(*args, **kwargs):
        response = make_response(view(*args, **kwargs))
        response.headers['Last-Modified'] = datetime.now()
        response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0'
        response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
        response.headers['Expires'] = '-1'
        return response
    return update_wrapper(no_cache, view)


@app.route(r'/')
@nocache
def landingpage():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: You can potentially serve the image via a script, then revoke access when the time is up, but practically once the image is sent to the client there will be ways for the client to retrieve it, if they try hard enough.

Comment: The source can not be edited. You may load the image using an ajax request an attach it to document.  However the history of network activities is still available in browser console.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour what do you mean by attaching it to the document?

Comment: For example get the image address by ajax request and set it as src of an empty image tag. `$("#myimg").attr("src",imageurl);`

Answer (score 0):

***First and foremost your images won't be protected if the user tries hard enough. You cannot prevent them for taking screen shots or anything of the sort.***

There are several ways to help "prevent" them from getting your images:

You can load your image via ajax:

```
<script>
    $('#my_image').attr('src', {{ url_for('image_path') }});
</script>
```

You can also load via an expiring hash key (database driven). So create a table with a mapping to the file name and then load the image using a route by passing in the hash key. If they try to open the image from a debugger, it can say it was expired and won't load the image.

```
def get_image(self, hash_key):
    my_image = self.image_engine.get_image(hash_key)
    if my_image.get('is_viewed') == 0:
        real_key = my_image.get('real_key')
        root_path = os.path.join(self.image_path, real_key)
        # call a function to set the image as "viewed"
        return send_from_directory(root_path, '{}.png'.format(real_key))
    else:
        return render_template('404.html')
```

Doing it like this means you can add expiration to the hash key, or even a flag that says it was already viewed and then render nothing, or a 404 if they try to load it again.

This method does require a lot more database calls, but if you are out to protect your images, you will have to look at some performance options.